# SQL using C++ - Where is the bottleneck?

Tags: c++, mysql, linux, mariadb

I'm attempting to read a plain text file line by line, construct an SQL INSERT statement, execute the query, and move on. Presently, I've got a solution that can complete about 200 lines per second on my ~4 year old desktop. However, I've got about 120 million lines to go through and was looking to implement this as a daily task. Taking a few hours to complete it would be fine, but taking nearly a week isn't an option.

The lines will contain one string and anywhere from 5 to 9 integers that range from boolean values (which I've encoded as TINYINT(1)) to microseconds since midnight (BIGINT).

Once read in from the file (via getline()) the lines are tokenized by this function:

```
#define MAX_TOKENS 10
#define MAX_TOKEN_LENGTH 32

char tokens[MAX_TOKENS][MAX_TOKEN_LENGTH];

//...

void split_line(const string &s)
{
  char raw_string[MAX_TOKENS * MAX_TOKEN_LENGTH];
  char *rest;
  char *token_string;

  strcpy(raw_string, s.c_str());

  if(tokens[0][0] != '\0')
  {
    fill(tokens[0], tokens[0]+(MAX_TOKENS*MAX_TOKEN_LENGTH), '\0');
  }

  for(uint32_t token = 0; token < MAX_TOKENS; token++)
  {
    if(token == 0) token_string = strtok_r(raw_string, " ", &rest);
    else token_string = strtok_r(nullptr, " ", &rest);

    if(token_string == nullptr) break;

    if(token >= 1)
    {
      //if it's not a number...
      if(token_string[0] < 48 || token_string[0] > 57)
      {
        if(token_string[0] != 45) //negative numbers are allowed
        {
          clear_tokens();
          break;
        }
      }
    }

    strcpy(tokens[token], token_string);
  }
}
```

I had tried a more STL derived version of that tokenizer, but that was proving too slow. It still ranks high in the callgraph, but not as high as it did with proper STL strings.

Anyway, the next step is to build the SQL query. For this, I've tried a few things. One option was stringstreams.

```
string insert_query = "INSERT INTO data_20170222";
stringstream values;
string query;

while(getline(input_stream, input_stream_line))
{
  split_line(input_stream_line);

  if(tokens[5][0] != '\0')  //the smallest line will have six tokens
  {
    try
    {
      query = insert_query;
      uint32_t item_type = stoi(tokens[2]);

      switch(item_type)
      {
        case 0: //one type of item
        case 1: //another type of item
        {
          values << " (valueA, valueB, valueC, valueD, valueE, valueF,"
                    " valueG, valueH) values('"
                 << tokens[0] << "', " << tokens[1] << ", "
                 << tokens[2] << ", "  << tokens[3] << ", "
                 << tokens[4] << ", "  << tokens[5] << ", "
                 << tokens[6] << ", "  << tokens[7] << ")";
          break;
        }
        //...
      }

        query.append(values.str());
        values.str(string());
        values.clear();

        if(mysql_query(conn, query.c_str()))
        {
          string error(mysql_error(conn));
          mysql_close(conn);
          throw runtime_error(error);
        }
      }
      catch(exception &ex)
      {
        cerr << "Error parsing line\n  '" << input_stream_line
             << "'\n" << "  " << ex.what() << endl;
        throw;
      }
    }
```

When I run this version, I see 30% of callgrind's samples being measured in std::operator<< within std::basic_ostream.

I originally tried doing this all with strings, ala:

```
string values;
values = " (valueA, valueB, valueC, valueD, valueE, valueF,"
         " valueG, valueH) values('" +
         string(tokens[0]) + "', " + tokens[1] + ", "
         tokens[2] + ", "  + tokens[3] + ", "
         tokens[4] + ", "  + tokens[5] + ", "
         tokens[6] + ", "  + tokens[7] + ")";
```

That proves to be effectively the same speed, but this time with the 30% of samples being allocated to std::operator+ from std::basic_string.

And finally, I switched to straight sprintf().

```
char values[MAX_TOKENS * MAX_TOKEN_LENGTH];
sprintf(values, " (valueA, valueB, valueC, valueD, valueE, valueF,"
        " valueG, valueH) values('%s', %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
        tokens[0], tokens[1], tokens[2], tokens[3],
        tokens[4], tokens[5], tokens[6], tokens[7]);
```

stringstream was slightly faster than string (though, well within a reasonable margin of error). sprintf() was about 10% faster than both, but that's still not fast enough.

Surely there's a well-established method for accomplishing this task with such large data sets. I'd be grateful for any guidance at this point.

## EDIT

Oh wow. I commented out the call to mysql_query() on a whim. Turns out, despite what valgrind says, that's where all my slowdown is. Without that block, it jumps from 200 lines per second to 1.2 million lines per second. That's more like it! Too bad I need the data in a database...

I guess this has become a question about why MariaDB seems to be operating so slowly, now. I've got a good SSD in this system, 16GB RAM, etc. It strikes me as unlikely that my hardware is holding it back.

All the more curious. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You probably need to do this inside a transaction. It also may help if your DB settings were optimized for your machine.

Comment: What does inside a transaction mean?

Comment: A database transaction. Read the documentation for your DB engine. Also, if you are repeating the same `INSERT` query for each line, just with different values, consider pre-preparing the query one time before reading the file, and then re-run the prepared query each time giving it new values. Prepared parameterized queries run a lot faster than running whole new queries over and over.

Comment: I bet they do. It occurred to me while walking the dog that if I could make the insert statements compound (say, 1,000 at a time) I'd be calling the API a whole lot less. So far, though, I haven't figured out how to do that.

Comment: most/all databases have external utiltites (or other features) to read files without you having to code anything more than a cfg file and the cmd-line, i.e. `bcp -u$uid -p$pswd -D$db -t$tbl -c$cfgFile -i$InFile -$l${logFile} -e${errFile"` (or similar). Ask around your organization, there must someone that has already figured this out (and it will be highly optimized code with strong error detection (which you'll have to learn how to decipher ;-) ). Good luck.

Comment: I would like to note that I highly doubt that your parser is the slow down. Its the volume of SQL transactions, there is a decent amount of overhead for each call, so if you could combine multiple calls into one single call, that could help, Like `INSERT INTO table (col1,col2) VALUES (line1c1,line1c2),(line2c1,line2c3),...,(lineN1,lineN2);`

Comment: As you haven't provided the SQL you are executing, your question is now off-topic.

Comment: @shellter - Thank you. That's exactly what I wound up doing last night after comments pointed me towards it. SQL has a LOAD DATA INFILE query that goes quite fast.

Comment: @GarriganStafford - Yessir. Wound up using some good old formatted output and letting SQL read it in from a file thusly. =) Worked like a charm. I'm going to try an experiment to compare that functionality to prepared statements today, too.

Comment: @EJP - I did. It's a whole slew of inserts that are constructed and called once per loop iteration, at most. There's no one place in the source where the query is whole, that's true. But I figured having it as I was running it was more important, in this case.

Comment: @musabi You did what? You didn't provide the SQL, which is the only thing I've mentioned.

Comment: The SQL looks like "INSERT INTO data_20170222" appended with " (valueA, valueB, valueC, valueD, valueE, valueF, valueG, valueH) values('%s', %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)" in various states. Then a call to mysql_query() with the resulting string.

Answer (score 0):

Batch `INSERTing` 100 rows per `INSERT` statement will run 10 times as fast.

Do you need to insert 120M rows per day?  That's 1400 per second.  Have you calculated how soon before you run out of disk space?

Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  Don't use `BIGINT` (8 bytes) when `INT` (4 bytes) will suffice.  Don't use `INT` when `MEDIUMINT` (3 bytes) will do.  Etc.

What will you do with a zillion rows of data?  Keep in mind that a poorly formed `SELECT` against a poorly indexed table will take a long time, even with SSDs.

Can the one string be normalized?

Think about packing a bunch of booleans into a `SET` (1 byte per 8 booleans) or some size int.

Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the main `SELECTs`.

What is the value of `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit`?  Use 2.